# Stripe PHP 3D secure payment without Stripe.JS?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm not using Stripe.JS because I need custom UI. I have collected card information from my customer. I'm using the PHP SDK.  My workflow is:

- create customer
- add/attach payment method to customer
- create payment intent

Every works fine. Now the issue that is if the end user uses a 3D secure card, I get a `next_action` in the response:

```
"next_action": {
    "type": "use_stripe_sdk",
    "use_stripe_sdk": {
      "type": "three_d_secure_redirect",
      "stripe_js": "https://hooks.stripe.com/redirect/authenticate/xxxxxx?client_secret=src_client_secret_xxxxxxx",
      "source": "src_xxxxxx"
    }
  },
  "next_source_action": {
    "type": "use_stripe_sdk",
    "use_stripe_sdk": {
      "type": "three_d_secure_redirect",
      "stripe_js": "https://hooks.stripe.com/redirect/authenticate/src_xxxxxx?client_secret=src_client_secret_xxxxxx",
      "source": "src_xxxxxx"
    }
  },
```

The documentation then relies on Stripe.JS for this step to open a verification popup. I'm not using Stripe.JS for the first part of the implementation due to custom UI. Can I use Stripe.JS for this part only? Or how do I do this part WITHOUT using Stripe.JS ? How do I know if this next step is successful so I can confirm the payment? I also see in my dev dashboard that the payment so successful (confusing). But the documentation says I still need to confirm that payment intent?

Comment: To be honest Stripe used to be amazing but they've some how made its development very confusing, more recently. I would however suggest you contact Stripe Support and ask them this very question -- I've had similar queries and they've been very helpful in resolving them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe has [documentation about handling 3D Secure manually without Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure#when-to-use-3d-secure) which will guide you through what you need to do.

That said, you can [create your own custom payment form with Stripe.js using Stripe Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js#elements), which is strongly recommended to increase security and reduce your PCI compliance burden.

Comment: My response have no "redirect_to_url" but "use_stripe_sdk" but I don't use the Stipe.JS

Comment: That's because you're not specifying a `return_url` when confirming the Payment Intent.  See here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure#confirm-payment-intent  Specifying `return_url` when confirming is how you tell Stripe you're not going to use Stripe.js for 3D Secure.

Answer (score 0):

check https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration-synchronous#elements-step-3. You need to use stripe.js, just to handle 3D secure.
Also check this example:

pay.php:

```
<?php

require './../vendor/autoload.php';

// This is your test secret API key.
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_51M5C27LYhXp3iY7Hp8Oz2PRPoUpYXbkTzMcx4xuiEmqayIIJTbGe1uTE2gtPg3mhJJpmoOBnFzZna9eQYr3xmV6T006etitKBC');

header('Content-Type: application/json');

try {
  $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_test_51M5C27LYhXp3iY7Hp8Oz2PRPoUpYXbkTzMcx4xuiEmqayIIJTbGe1uTE2gtPg3mhJJpmoOBnFzZna9eQYr3xmV6T006etitKBC');

  $cardData = [
    'number' => '4000000000003220',
    'exp_month' => 12,
    'exp_year' => 2029,
    'cvc' => '314',
  ];

  $paymentData = [
    'amount' => 1400,
    'currency' => 'usd',
  ];


  $token = $stripe->tokens->create([
    'card' => $cardData,
  ]);

  $paymentMethod = $stripe->paymentMethods->create([
    'type' => 'card',
    'card' => $cardData,
  ]);

  
  // Create a PaymentIntent with amount and currency
  $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
      'amount' => $paymentData['amount'],
      'currency' => $paymentData['currency'],
      'payment_method' => $paymentMethod,
      'confirmation_method' => 'manual' // required to make 3d secure work
  ]);

  $payment = $stripe->paymentIntents->confirm(
    $paymentIntent->id, 
    [
      'return_url' => 'YOUR_URL'
    ]);

  if($payment->status == 'succeeded' || $payment->status == 'pending') echo json_encode(['redirect' => './succeed.php']);
  // check if the status === requires_action, it means that 3D secure is required
  elseif ($payment->status == 'requires_action') {
    // Tell the client to handle the action
    echo json_encode([
      'requiresAction' => true,
      'clientSecret' => $paymentIntent->client_secret
    ]);
    exit();
  } 
  else echo json_encode(['unexpected_error' => true]);

  $charge = $stripe->charges->create([
    'source' => $token,
    'currency' => $paymentData['currency'],
    'amount' => $paymentData['amount'],
    'description' => 'My First Test Charge (created for API docs at https://www.stripe.com/docs/api)',
  ]);

} catch (Error $e) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
```

pay.js:

```
// This is your test publishable API key.
const stripe = Stripe("pk_test_51M5C27LYhXp3iY7HJOk6mEZu6caLGHi8QzyaAgMK1Ek1X7W8yeSSkeMVTTg9tO0S8UPnGX4Qo0tSJQzjJuUavbaH00qAFwCPbw");

document
  .querySelector("#payment-form")
  .addEventListener("submit", handleSubmitBackend);

async function handleSubmitBackend(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let response = await fetch("./php/pay.php", {
    method: "POST",
  });
  let result = await response.json();
  console.log(result);
  if (result.requiresAction) {
    // Use Stripe.js to handle the required card action
    const { error: errorAction, paymentIntent } = await stripe.handleCardAction(result.clientSecret);

    if (errorAction) {
      // Show error from Stripe.js in payment form
      console.log(errorAction);
    } else {
      // The card action has been handled
      // The PaymentIntent can be confirmed again on the server
      const serverResponse = await fetch('/pay.php', {
        method: 'POST',
      });
    }
  }
  else if(result.redirect) {
    window.location.href = result.redirect;
  }
}
```